# Use headless wayland / sway when testing on GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions, headless, wayland

I am trying to run a test suite on GitHub Actions for a package that wraps utilities for calling the clipboard on a variety of platforms. While I have managed to get headless testing set up for a Linux system using X11, based on running `xvfb`, I am struggling to find documentation for how to set up a headless Wayland-based system for testing the utility [wl-clipboard](https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard).

The [current action I'm running](https://github.com/mdlincoln/clipr/blob/03ab48e937a6b3b1ed1ada4d1eff9dd037f94fe2/.github/workflows/R-CMD-check.yaml#L102-L128) installs sway, creates the required `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`, and then runs `sway`. I suspect I am not starting `sway` correctly because I can't seem to get it to startup and stay running in the background while the rest of the tests run.

```
      - name: Install wayland
        if: ${{ matrix.config.clip_type == 'wayland' }}
        run: |
          mkdir $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
          chown $USER $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
          chmod 0700 $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
          sudo apt-get update
          sudo apt-get purge x11-*
          sudo apt-get install sway meson libwayland-dev
          echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
          ls -la $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
          sway -d -V
          cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/..
          git clone https://github.com/bugaevc/wl-clipboard.git
          cd wl-clipboard
          meson build
          cd build/
          sudo ninja install
          wl-copy --primary
          wl-paste --primary
          cd $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
        env:
          XDG_RUNTIME_DIR: /home/runner/work/clipr/xdg
          WLR_BACKENDS: headless
          WLR_LIBINPUT_NO_DEVICES: 1
          WAYLAND_DISPLAY: wayland-1
          GTK_USE_PORTAL: 0
```

[See the verbose logs from `sway`.](https://github.com/mdlincoln/clipr/runs/4417699988?check_suite_focus=true) Running `sway` like this in the foreground, it just hangs indefinitely. Naively trying to run sway in the background using `nohup sway &` results in the later calls to the utilities saying `Failed to connect to a Wayland server`.

Any suggestions for getting a headless Wayland server up and running?

Comment: Have you head any luck? I'm looking for the same, and this is the first result the duck gives when searching for "headless wayland".

Comment: @Alexandros unfortunately not yet